# Xamarin Forms AppShell - FlyoutItem maximum contents

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I am implementing an App Shell with flyout menu as per code below

I have what appears to be a strange outcome when the contents of my `FlyoutItem` list get above a certain number.

In the example below, if there are five `ShellContent` items, it works absolutely fine.

However, any more than that, and instead of the actual target page you expect to see when you click on the `FlyoutMenu` page, you instead are presented with a default white list view in the main panel in which MORE is given as title and the items which "don't fit" are listed, with no way to return to the Flyout menu

Note I cannot simply have more than one `FlyoutMenu` grouping as I am trying to resolve a very nasty problem whereby if there is more than one, and you swap between them, you end up with a history array of pages before getting back to the index page.

```
<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">

        <ShellContent Route="routeone"
                      Title="PAGE ONE"
                      Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:PageOne}">

        </ShellContent>

        <ShellContent Route="routetwo"
                      Title="PAGE TWO"
                      Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:PageTwo}">
        </ShellContent>
```

Comment: Could you provide the code about the certsin number of FlyoutItem list which get the error? And what FlyoutMenu grouping you want to resolve?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT It happens in James M's Xaminals demo too. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/Xaminals It so happens there are five ShellContent items in his FlyoutItem. If you add a sixth, this happens:

Comment: I would check it and feedback ASAP.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Thank you - also posted details including screen shot here https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/issues/634

Comment: Thanks for sharing. We would follow on Github.

Comment: Is this issue still happening?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understand the problem but I have a FlyoutPage in an App Shell with 9 contents. I do see the "...More" button in the tabs and if I use it the menu with the other contents is showing up. If I click/touch on the background the menu disappears.